# How to introduce application-wide context object?

Tags: asp.net, .net, architecture

I need to make several properties accessible from application's business layer. Those are some ids and common settings. Most of them are valid only through request-response lifespan.
This is a web application (ASP.NET Web Forms to be specific) with dependency injection set up.

Currently those properties are passed through method parameters directly to business layer's services. That works but is not very efficient since:

- sometimes parameters' values need to be passed deeper obscuring the readability a bit
- some properties should be lazy resolved, and this should be done only once per request
- retrieving properties which are resolved by touching a database can be confusing for new developers (there is not unified way of doing this)
- some services are constructed by a factory which enriches them with some config parameters

I was thinking about introducing an application context interface, with an implementation in the main project, which would be created on every request. It could be injected to the services directly making them *parametrized* automatically and independently (services won't need the factory anymore).

Is it how this problem should be tackled or maybe there are some other options?
One option I don't like here is that it might bond the main particle with business layer which is not a perfect example of [The Clean Architecture](http://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html).

Answer (score 0):

Id say you solution is a very common one - inject an 'application context' into your classes. One thing I would be careful of though is making sure you are following the Integration Segregation Principle (from SOLID). Dont just start making all your classes expect an application context instance. Instead, design interfaces that split the application context up, and have your classes expect them as dependencies. Your application context will then need to implement all the interfaces.

This is the correct way to do things as it decouples your classes from implementation. Really your classes don't care if their dependency is from one giant application context, they just care about specific methods implemented by it. This will make your code more robust as you will reduce the risk of breaking something if you change the implementation of the application context later on.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use some dependency injection container? Your global settings and parameters can be registered to it as pseudo-singletons and then you will be able to neatly request them from any point inside your application.